# c++ error in vs code - Runs but nothing happens

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

For any code I write, VS code compiles it and create a .exe file, but nothing happens after that.

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cout<<"enter age: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"age is "<<n;
return 0;
}
```

now, i know the code is correct, and something is wrong with either the compiler or vs code

I am running the code using ctrl+alt+n, or the run icon.

in the "code" windows below, it inputs the command

```
    PS C:\Users\sasik> cd "c:\Users\sasik\Documents\SHARAN\Coding\VS codes\" ; if ($?) { g++ Arrays_Basics.cpp -o Arrays_Basics } ; if ($?) { .\Arrays_Basics }
```

but after that, nothing happens. Please help.

Comment: What happens if you execute the .exe from CMD?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any more detail than [the first time you asked it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66757201/code-compiles-but-nothing-happens-after-that)

Comment: Just a thought: maybe your program is actually running and just waiting for you to type in an age and press Enter, after which the standard output will be flushed and you'll see all your program's output.